# Non deterministic behaviour with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

The following snippet using RxJS does not always yield the same result when executed in the browser (Chrome v70) ... why?

```
const result = [];

interval(40).subscribe(
  value => result.push(value)
);

setTimeout(() => {console.log(result);}, 180);
```

The logged `result` is sometimes `[0, 1, 2]` and sometimes `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

I would have expected the emission of values via `interval` and the check scheduled via `setTimeout` both to be scheduled via the JavaScript event loop. Therefore always four values should be emitted before the check.
Obviously this is not true ... why?

Comment: You might be misunderstanding how timeouts work in JS. Timeouts don't happen "when you say they should", they happen "*at least X ms from the moment you schedule them*". And given that `interval()` is still bound by the rules of JS, you'll want to see what's really going on, timing wise. Don't push `value`, instead push `{value, timestamp: Date.now()}` and then have a look at what's in the array after those 180ms. Are the timestamps _really_ 40ms apart?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You are right! I knew that timeouts happen "at least X ms from the moment you schedule them" but in my model the 4 emissions were scheduled before the check, so even if the emissions or the check have a delay, they should still be sequential ...
But that model is probably wrong, the second emission is probably only scheduled after the first emission has been executed, so if we have a delay here, it might be possible that the fourth emission then is executed after the execution of the check ...

Comment: John Resig explained it very nicely in his blog post 10years ago. https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/